# MySQL - Referencing aggregate column in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate

This seems so simple but I can't seem to figure it out without doing subqueries (which seem to slow down the queries significantly - takes almost 10 seconds instead of <1).

Let's say I have a table of sent documents, and I want to select the ones that have been updated since they've last been sent, and the ones that have never been sent.

```
SELECT d.document_id, max(sd.document_sent_date) as last_sent_date
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN sent_documents sd ON d.document_id=sd.document_id
WHERE last_sent_date is NULL OR last_sent_date<d.last_updated
GROUP BY d.document_id
```

Is something like this possible? Basically, I want to use the result of max() in my where clause.

Comment: +1 for exactly the title that I searched for.

Answer (score 10):

You want the `having` clause.

General rule: `where` operates on date *before* aggregation, `having` operates on data *after* aggregation.

Comment: More specifically: the predicates in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated when rows are accessed; predicates in the `HAVING` clause are evaluated after the result set is prepared, nearly last in the execution plan (just prior to processing the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses). So predicates in the HAVING clause can reference aggregates, as well as expressions and column aliases which are not accessible in a WHERE clause.