# How can I include an aggregated column in a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2 column table farmer_crops that stores the relationship between a farmer and the crops they cultivate. A farmer can cultivate either one or multiple crops. The query below gives me the distinct farmers and the total crops they cultivate. How can I get the total number of farmers who cultivate crops above one (my_crops > 1)?

```
select distinct farmer_id, count(crop_id) as my_crops 
from farmer_crops 
group by farmer_id
```

[edit] Using the hint from GMB, the query below gives me a total of 2330 rows which is correct.

```
SELECT farmer_id, count(crop_id) as my_crops 
FROM farmer_crops 
GROUP BY farmer_id
HAVING count(crop_id) > 1
```

However, what I really want is the query below, just the total number, but the total_farmers column returns the number 8330 which is wrong.

```
SELECT count(farmer_id) as total_farmers 
FROM farmer_crops
HAVING count(crop_id) > 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Referencing aggregate column in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638634/mysql-referencing-aggregate-column-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on aggregate expression can not be used in a `WHERE` clause. You need to use `HAVING` instead:

```
SELECT farmer_id, count(crop_id) as my_crops 
FROM farmer_crops 
GROUP BY farmer_id
HAVING count(crop_id) > 1
```

Unlike the `WHERE` clause, the `HAVING` clause comes *after* the `GROUP BY` clause.

NB : `SELECT DISTINCT` usually does not make sense with `GROUP BY`, I removed it.

Comment: Yes the `DISTINCT` was pretty much redundant because without or without the query would have given the same results so it can and should be removed for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on using HAVING. This still gives me multiple rows with a farmer and how many crops he cultivates. However, I want to get the **total number** of farmers doing multiple crops. So this should pretty much return just one row

Comment: @mkocansey: ah ok, I understood a little differently. Well, basically we just need to count the records returned by the other query, so you can simply wrap the query, like : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( -- the query -- ) AS x